# Заполнение массива на С

Tags: c

```
int A[2][2];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    scanf_s("%i", &A[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Вот такой простой код. В результате:

Вместо

```
123456789
```

Заполняется:

```
1234451123
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Ну как минимум массив у вас 2x2, а заполняете вы его как будто это массив 3x3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы объявляете массив `int A[2][2]`. Это значит, что он у Вас содержит две строки с индексами 0, 1 и два столбца с индексами 0, 1.

Далее, Вы запускаете цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

Т.е. цикл выполняется начиная с `i = 0` и до тех пор, пока `i < 3`. Таким образом `i` принимает значение 0, 1, 2. А строки с индексом 2 у Вас нет и Вы залезли в чужую память.

Аналогично для второго цикла

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
```

Таким образом, код должен быть таким

```
int A[2][2];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    scanf_s("%i", &A[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А есть какой-то способ проверки использования чужой памяти?
В Delphi был Range checking

Comment: @BlackDimkoss Не знаю. Задайте отдельный вопрос

Comment: @BlackDimkoss, в C - нет. Только постфактум, утилитами типа valgrind. Или анализаторами кода, например, PVS Studio.

Comment: А в C++ тоже нет?

Comment: @BlackDimkoss, С++ - это другой язык. Задайте новый вопрос (в котором, вангую, пошлют в маны типа этого http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array ).